# Find the positively invariant annulus

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, set-invariance

> Given the following dynamical system
>
> $$\begin{aligned} \dot r &= r(1-r^2) \\ \dot \theta &= r^2 \left( (1-r^2)^2 + \sin(\theta)^2 \right)\end{aligned}$$
>
> find the annulus $A$ defined as follows
>
> $$A(R_+, R_-) = \{(x,y) \mid R_-^2 \le x^2+y^2 \le R_+^2\}$$
>
> where this system is positively invariant.

My thinking was that for my annulus I would want $2$ circles $(R_-,R_+)$ and I by looking at the [phase flow](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot%5B%7Bx%281-x%5E2%29%2Cx%5E2%28%281-x%5E2%29%5E2%2Bsin%5E2%28y%29%29%7D%2C%7By%2C-2%2C2%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-2%2C2%7D%5D) and thought that $R_-$ would need to be 1, but I also thought that R_+ must also be 1. I thought that because I need the phase flow to be pointing outwards of my smaller circle $R_-$ for it to be positively invariant, but I'd need the phase flow to be pointing inward for our bigger circle $R_+$ so this happens at $1$ too.

I don't think my attempt is correct, but it is what I was thinking.

Comment: The variables $(r,\theta)$ are polar coordinates, so they are not really dummy variables as you intended in your plot. As for the annulus, the radius of two circles that form the annulus may be found by considering the sign of $\dot{r}$.

Comment: @CheeHan So what youre saying is that my plot is wrong? And I don't understand what you mean about the sign of $\dot r$ sorry

Comment: @CheeHan After doing the conversion, I ended up with something like this http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot%5B%7B%28-x%5E2-y%5E2%2B1%29%28%28%28y%5E3%28x%5E2%2By%5E2-1%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E0.5%29%2Bx%29%29%2C+y%28-x%5E2-y%5E2%2B1%29%281-%28xy%28x%5E2%2By%5E2-1%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E0.5%29%7D%5D

Comment: I don't see you specifying $(x,y)$ as polar coordinates in your plot, so yes it is wrong. In terms of polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, what $\dot{\theta}$ does is telling you that the curve goes anticlockwise if $\dot\theta>0$ and clockwise if $\dot\theta<0$. On the other hand, the sign of $\dot r$ determines the radial direction of the curve. The radius increases as $t$ increases and vice versa.

Comment: So to construct a positively invariant annulus, you want to find the radius $R_1$ of the smaller such that $\dot r>0$ for all $0<r\le R_1$ and the radius $R_2>R_1$ of the larger circle such that $\dot r<0$ for all $r\ge R_2$.

Comment: I didn't check your conversion back to Cartesian coordinates but your plot looks like what I had in mind (:

Comment: @CheeHan Thanks for your help! Just one thing with the phase flow on the unit circle, I am struggling to see how it goes at this is the point where it is no longer positive invariant

Comment: Great observation! $r=1$ is the critical value that determines the sign of $\dot r$. If you choose $R_1<1$ and $R_2>1$, then for any $0<r\le R_1$, your curve, starting from the smaller circle, will travel forward into the annulus (since $\dot r>0$ for each $r\le R_1$) but it cannot exit the annulus since the curve approaches the unit circle as time evolves. Can you see why ?

Comment: @CheeHan Yeah, so for any point inside this unit circle (or outside for that matter) we're going to say that they have $\omega$-limit points at $(-1,0)$, $(1,0)$ depending on whether the point is in the upper or lower plane. The $\omega$-limit points are on the unit circle

Comment: Actually, I don't think what I just said is correct. I don't know what the limit cycles are. If I had to guess, I'd say the $\omega$-limit cycle is anywhere on the unit circle?

Comment: Well, we usually take $r\ge 0$. The $\omega$-limit set is the unit circle as you suspected. Going back to my point before, all $\dot\theta$ tells you is whether you're going clockwise or anticlockwise. So $\dot r$ is going to tell you what your limit cycle would be, but you should keep in mind that sometimes it is not possible to tell, for example if you have a complicated expression for $\dot r$. In that case, you might try to sketch the streamline first as that will help you guess if there is a positively invariant set.

Comment: @CheeHan Oh I see what you mean, this applies for any point in the plane that isn't on the unit circle though? As I am asked to find the $\omega$-limit set of the points found on the unit circle. But as I showed before, the unit circle are the fixed points, so does this just mean tha the $\omega$-limit set for points on the unit circle are just the unit circle again?

Comment: Yesssssssssssss!